# Could not open file or uri for loading certificate from 3c675stf21-certificate.pem.crt

Tags: amazon-web-services, openssl, iot

I am trying to convert a .crt certificate to a .der file.
The tutorial tells me I need to change the file name from xxxxx-certificate.crt to xxxxx-certificate.pem.crt. I am using openssl to convert the file and it seems to work on a .crt file but not on .pem.crt file.
Here is the link to the tutorial
https://nerdyelectronics.com/how-to-convert-certificates-from-pem-to-der-format/
This is the link to the tutorial. [image]

openssl x509 -in xxxxxxxxxx-certificate.pem.crt -out cert.der -outform DER

Answer (score 1):

The file xxxxx-certificate.pem.crt doesn't exist. The error is clear.

Whatever certificate name you downloaded from AWS, use that.

By the way, the tutorial didn't ask you to change from .crt to .pem.crt but from xxxxxxxxxx-certificate.**pem.crt.**txt**** So now just rename that document to xxxxxxxxxx-certificate.**pem.crt**